# accessing object and its relations in laravel 4.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I hope I can explain this clearly, apologies in advance if it is confusing.  I have a goals table which hasOne of each of bodyGoalDescs, strengthGoalDescs and distanceGoalDescs as shown below

goals.php

```
class Goal extends BaseModel
{
    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();

    //define relationships

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'id', 'userId');
    }

    public function goalStatus()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('GoalStatus', 'id', 'goalStatus');
    }

    public function bodyGoalDesc()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('BodyGoalDesc', 'id', 'bodyGoalId');
    }

    public function distanceGoalDesc()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('DistanceGoalDesc', 'id', 'distanceGoalId');
    }

    public function strengthGoalDesc()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('StrengthGoalDesc', 'id', 'strengthGoalId');
    }

    //goal specific functions

    public static function yourGoals()
    {
        return static::where('userId', '=', Auth::user()->id)->paginate();
    }
}
```

each of the three tables looks like this with the function details changed

```
class BodyGoalDesc extends BaseModel
{
    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'bodyGoalDescs';

    //define relationships
    public function goal()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Goal', 'bodyGoalId', 'id');
    }

}
```

a goal has either a body goal, a strength goal, or a distance goal. I am having a problem with this method in the controller function

```
<?php

class GoalsController extends BaseController
{
    protected $goal;

    public function __construct(Goal $goal)
    {
        $this->goal = $goal;
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int      $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $thisgoal = $this->goal->find($id);

        foreach ($this->goal->with('distanceGoalDesc')->get() as $distancegoaldesc) {
            dd($distancegoaldesc->DistanceGoalDesc);
        }

    }
}
```

when I pass through goal 1 which has a distance goal the above method dies and dumps the Goal object with the details of goal 1 and an array of its relations including an object with DistanceGoalDes.

when I pass through goal 2 it passes through exactly the same as if I had passed through goal 1

if I dd() $thisgoal i get the goal that was passed through

what I want ultimately is a method that returns the goal object with its relevant goal description object to the view but this wont even show me the correct goal details not too mind with the correct relations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this function is now doing what I want it to do, I am sure there is a better way (besides the fact that its happening in the controller right now) and I would love to hear it.

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $thisgoal = $this->goal->find($id);

        if (!$thisgoal->bodyGoalDesc == null) {
            $goaldesc = $thisgoal->bodyGoalDesc;

            return View::make('goals.show')
                ->with('goal', $thisgoal)
                ->with('bodygoaldesc', $goaldesc);
        } elseif (!$thisgoal->strengthGoalDesc == null) {
            $goaldesc = $thisgoal->strengthGoalDesc;

            return View::make('goals.show')
                ->with('goal', $thisgoal)
                ->with('strengthgoaldesc', $goaldesc);
        } elseif (!$thisgoal->distanceGoalDesc == null) {
            $goaldesc = $thisgoal->distanceGoalDesc;

            return View::make('goals.show')
                ->with('goal', $thisgoal)
                ->with('distancegoaldesc', $goaldesc);
        }

    }
```